# Backbone: Click event re-renders child view

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone-events

```
var LandingView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        console.log('Landing View has been initialized');
        this.render();
    },

    template: Handlebars.compile($('#landingPage').html()),

    render: function() {
         this.$el.html(this.template);
    },

    events: {
        // I want to render the subview on click
        'click .btn-login' : 'renderlogin',
    },

    renderlogin: function() {
        // Is this the right way to instantiate a subview?
        var loginpage = new LoginView({ el: $('#modal-content') });
    }
});
```

And my next view, which basically just empties the $('#modal-content') element...

```
var LoginView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        this.render();
        console.log("login view initialized");
    },

    template: Handlebars.compile($('#loginPage').html()),

    render: function() {
        this.delegateEvents();
        this.$el.html(this.template);
    },

    events: {
        // this is where things get super confusing...
        // Upon clicking, LoginView gets re-initialized and
        // subsequent clicks are called for each number of times 
        // the view is initialized.
        'click .js-btn-login' : 'login'
    },

    login: function(e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        var self = this;
        console.log($(this.el).find('#userSignIn #userEmail').val());
        console.log($(this.el).find('#userSignIn #userPassword').val());
    }
});
```

My templates:

LANDING PAGE:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars-template" id="landingPage">
    <div>
       <div class="auth-wrapper">
            <div class="logo">
                <img src="img/login/logo-landing.png"/>
            </div>
            <div class="to-auth-buttons-wrapper">
                <a class="btn-to-auth btn-signup" href="#">Sign Up</a>
                <a class="btn-to-auth btn-login" href="#">Log In</a>
           </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</script>
```

LOGINPAGE:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars-template" id="loginPage">
    <div>
        <div class="header">
            <a href="#" class="btn back-to-landing">Back</a>
        </div>
        <div class="auth-wrapper">


           <div class="logo">
                <img src="img/login/logo-landing.png"/>
           </div>

           <form method="post" id="userSignIn">       
                <input class="form-control input-signin" type="text" name="useremail" placeholder="Email" id="userEmail" value="tester"> 
                <input class="form-control input-signin" type="password" name="userpass" placeholder="Password" id="userPassword">
                <button class="btn-to-auth btn-login js-btn-login">Log In</button>
           </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</script>
```

**My goal:**

1. From within LandingView, upon clicking .btn-login, render LoginView.
2. From within LoginView, upon clicking .js-btn-login, console.log
   contents of form

**Problems:**

1. In LoginView, upon clicking .js-btn-login, I see that the initialize function is called again.
2. In LoginView, I can't use jquery to get the values inside of $('#userSignIn #userEmail').val() and $('#userSignIn #userEmail').val() because they aren't there on render. I see the initial hardcoded value ( `input[value="tester"]`) but this is all it sees.

**My question:**

How do I get the view to stop reinitializing on an event firing and how do I get the values in my DOM after rendering?

Comment: I guess you have a zoombie view. Checkout this article [Zombies! RUN!](http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/09/15/zombies-run-managing-page-transitions-in-backbone-apps/) It may help.

Comment: Try removing the class btn-login from the button om the loginpage template